# Is there other function $f$ such that $f(x, y) + f(y, z) \geq 2f(x,z)$? What is it name?

Tags: functions, definition, axioms

Let function $f: \mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfy the following conditions: For all $x, y, z\in \mathbb R^d$,

- **Non-negativity:** $f(x, y)\geq 0$
- **Identity:** $f(x, x)=0$
- **"Convexity":** $f(x, z) \leq \frac{1}{2}f(x, y) + \frac{1}{2}f(y, z)$

Is there a function which satisfies all above properties and is there a name for such class of functions?

**Edit:** I thought that $f_1(x, y)=||x-y||^2$ satisfies all the conditions, however, it does not satisfy the last condition as figured out by @WhatUp in the comment below.

Comment: Do you mean $f: \mathbb R^{2d} \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: @MartinR yes, I fixed it, and changed the name "concavity" to 'convexity"

Comment: @WhatsUp here I assume that $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm

Comment: What about $d = 1, x = 0, y = 1, z = 2$? Your definition actually looks quite similar to a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition) on $\Bbb R^d$.

Comment: @WhatsUp yeah you are right, $||x-y||^2$ does not satisfy that "convexity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(a, b) + f(b, b) \geq 2 f(a, b)
$$
$$
f(b, b) \geq f(a, b)
$$
$$
0 \geq f(a, b)
$$
Since we also have $f(a, b) \geq 0$, the only solution is the constant function $f(a, b) = 0$.

Comment: wao, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The name for this class of functions is

> constant-zero functions.

---

Consider $x,y,z$ and let
$$ A=\max\{f(x,y),f(x,z),f(y,z),f(y,x),f(z,x),f(z,y)\}.$$
Wlog., $f(x,z)=A$. Then by "convexity", $f(x,y)=f(y,z)=A$. By "convexity" again (applied to $(y,z,x)$ instead of $(x,y,z)$), also $f(y,x)=A$ and in a similar way ultimately also $f(z,x)=f(z,y)=A$.
Thus

**Lemma.** For all $x,y,z$,
$$f(x,y)=f(x,z)=f(y,z)=f(z,x)=f(z,y)=f(y,x).$$

Apply the lemma to $z=x$, to find

**Theorem.** For all $x,y$, $$f(x,y)=0.$$

Comment: yah, thank you for your detail answer, 1 upvote, btw, the answer of mathmandan is also simple as well!